# be vain about (appearance, achievements)

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does "be vain about something" (appearance/achivement etc.) mean?   I know who is vain person but I'm not quite sure when it comes to be vain about something.

Comment: This is redundant, **to be vain** already means **excessively proud of or concerned about one's own appearance, qualities, achievements** ([dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vain)).

Comment: Do you think to be excessively proud of  appearance and be concerned about it are the same thing?   I have already checked those dictionaries which suggest these two options as you pointed out.  If I take too much pride in my appearence I'd think myself as the one of 7 miracles in world and that would plobably lead me to be arrogant, conceited at times but If I was concerned about my look I'd be tend to check my reflection in the mirror all the time, I'd worry about not looking perfect and that means I'm obsessed with my look but doesn't mean I'm very confident about my look.

Comment: You understand what the dictionary meaning of "vain" is, right?  To be vain about something in particular is just to be that way regarding that particular aspect.  For example, someone might be vain about their appearance, but not about their achievements.

Comment: Let's do a quiz like that to firm up the understanding : Just replace the phrase "vain about" with a closest synonym in this sentence - "She's very vain about her appearance". What would be your synonym?